# Hey guys n girls! I'm trying to find a way to hide the users input in the terminal from IntelliJ when I run a kt

Tags: kotlin, input, terminal, hide

```
fun main(){
   println("Enter your password: ")
   var password = readln()
 }
```

Enter your password: *******

Is there any way to get this work in the terminal? I already tried a little with System.'in' and Inputstream but I can't find a solution

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is not a full terminal emulator, and it does not support advanced terminal features such as turning off echo. The usual way to read passwords - such as using `System.console().readPassword()` - does not work in IntelliJ IDEA's console.